# Rad Editor in DNN - Target popup window

Tags: dotnetnuke, radeditor

I am using the new DNN Telerik Rad editor and I looked for this option within its link manager and while I found a target pull down menu the options in this pull down menu were the following:

- none
- Same Window
- New Window
- Parent Window
- Browser Window
- Search Pane
- Media Pane
- CUSTOM TARGETS[Add Custom Target...]

When I opted to try the Add Custom target and got by the popup blocker I did see that I was given a textbox where I could add a custom target other than what was in the drop down list but none of these options seemed to indicate a way to quickly target a popup window and tweak its attributes like you could with the fckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

The requested functionality is not supported out-of-the box by RadEditor link manager. What you can do is to customize this dialog yourself - see this demo as a base http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/externaldialogspath/defaultcs.aspx
or 
request it as a feature in the AJAX feedback portal: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108

Rumen